# how to get updated the component which is connected to redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have two components one is App component and other is counter component.Here App component is root component and counter component is child component.I used redux in this application.
In index component in subscribe method i am receiving updated value.
Here the problem is in Counter component how to receive update if any changes in redux store.?

```
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Counter from './Counter';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const initialState = {
  count: 0
}
function reducer(state=initialState,action) {
  if(action.type === "INCREMENT"){
    return [...state,{count: state.count + 1}]
  }
  if(action.type === "DECREMENT"){
    return [...state,{count: state.count - 1}]
  }
  return state;
}
export const store = createStore(reducer);

store.subscribe(() =>{
  console.log("state value",store.getState()[0].count);
})


const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Counter
    />
  </Provider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


--------------------------
//Counter.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './index';
class Counter extends React.Component {

  increment(){
    store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT',payload: 1})
  }
  decrement(){
    store.dispatch({type: 'DECREMENT',payload: 1});

  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    console.log("Props",this.props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Counter</h2>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}>-</button>
          <span>{this.props.count}</span>
          <button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => (
{count: state.count}

);
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
```

Comment: Did you map your component to props ? If not, please look at this:  https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components

Comment: Any connected component will automatically receive new props from store updates. There is nothing to do additionally.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't need to return an array in reducer as the initial state of youer app is object. You have to just "return a new object". And remember to never mutate the state in reducer as it was designed to be a pure function that means without any side effects. 
You also need to add mapDispatchToProps as you use action dispatchers in your Counter component, so that connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)